# What is the difference between element and text node

Tags: javascript, html, dom

What is the basic difference between an element node and a text node? In JS in a DOM tree as `innerHTML` is only valid for *element nodes*. I'm curious to know the difference so I can understand `innerHTML` completely.

Comment: Pretty simple, all texts are `Text Nodes`, and all elements (tags)  are `Element Nodes`. For example `<body>Hello World</body>` is the text node `Hello World` that is the content of the element node `body`. In any case, you should not use `innerHTML` anymore. It is slow (requires to reparse the DOM) and poses a security risk (XSS injection).

Answer (score 0):

A *Text node* is basically only text, like "hello, world!". E.g. text can't have child elements or attributes. See ["Text" in the WebApi reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text).

An *Element* is basically almost everything else, see ["Element" in the WebApi reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).